# PHP PhantomJS - "use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;" Error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, namespaces, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I've installed PhantomJS and PHP-PhantomJS per the PHP-PhantomJS [docs](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/).

Per the PHP-PhantomJS docs, I have the following lines at the top of a php file:

```
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;
$client = Client::getInstance();
```

When executing `$client = Client::getInstance();`, I get the error:

> 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client' not found

The installer has placed `JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client` here:

> /Applications/myWebApp/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client.php

The script that contains the "use" command is located here:

> /Applications/myWebApp/application/controllers/myPHPscript.php

How can I modify the "use" command so as to locate the required "JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client" file?

I have looked at StackOverflow topics that appear similar but don't seem to provide the answer I need.

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, I followed the PHP-PhantomJS Docs in installing PhantomJS and PHP-PhantomJS.  Per those docs, I used Composer to download and install everything. I'd never used Composer before. I learned that the framework I'm using, CodeIgniter, includes support for Composer. All I had to do was activate Composer support in the CodeIgniter config.php file, via the `$config['composer_autoload']` setting.